# Looping through Mustache JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am having trouble getting the data from JSON to insert into individual divs. I would like each of the image/videourls to insert into their own

```
<div class="item"></div>
```

Currently, each object gets inserted on top of eachother (with my given template HTML) in the "item" class. I figure that there must be away to tell Mustache to insert each object in the array into it's own div with the class "item" so that the final result will be two divs with the HTML in the template inside each one.

I have JSON data:

```
{ "pictures" : [
  {
    "image": "1",
    "videourl": "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
  },
  {
    "image": "4",
    "videourl": "http://www.youtube.com/embed"
  }
]}
```

and I have a template setup:

```
{{#pictures}}

    <div class="videoplay-main animated fadeIn" data-videourl="{{videourl}}">
        <img src="img/frontpage/{{image}}.jpg" />
    </div>

{{/pictures}}
```

And I have JS:

```
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data){
    var homeTemplate = $("#slider-template").html();
    var html = Mustache.render(homeTemplate, data);
    $('.item').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then you have to do it this way:

```
{{#pictures}}
   <div class="item">
      <div class="videoplay-main animated fadeIn" data-videourl="{{videourl}}">
         <img src="img/frontpage/{{image}}.jpg" />
      </div>
   </div>
{{/pictures}}
```

Comment: Whoa, not sure how that slipped my mind when it is so logical. Dimitar, I should be shunned for this one.

Comment: @James Nah dude :) Sometimes you stare at a problem for too long, it happens to me all the time.

Comment: Thanks for help and encouragement! Amazing.